# Symfony 1.4: how to install multiple projects on the same server?

Tags: php, deployment, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need to install two different projects developed with Symfony 1.4. Each project is independent, with its own database and configuration. I need something like the following:

```
/project1/apps
/project1/config
/project1/lib
.
.
.
/project2/apps
/project2/config
/project2/lib
.
.
.

/htdocs/project1/index.php
/htdocs/project2/index.php
```

How should I set up **index.php** and **ProjectConfiguration.class.php** files, each project?
I tried several options but none of them work.
The last option I tried was:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
require_once('/../project1/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
```

And **ProjectConfiguration.class.php** :

```
<?php

require_once '/../project1/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');

    $this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/htdocs/project1');
    $this->setCacheDir('/tmp/symfony_cache');
    $this->setLogDir('/tmp/symfony_logs');
```

But it does not work:

Warning: require_once(/../project1/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/mydomain.com/htdocs/project1/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/../project1/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php' (include_path='./:/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php') in /www/mydomain.com/htdocs/project1/index.php on line 2

Comment: You might simply need to use absolute paths instead of relative : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew, Thank you very much. You are right. I solved the problem!

Comment: In index.php, I write: require_once('/www/mydomain.com/project1/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php'); and again in ProjectConfiguration.class.php: require_once '/www/mydomain.com/project1/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';

Comment: Glad to know it helped. If that link helped you, feel free to upvote the question and/or the answer, and to mark your question as a duplicate of it